# Put two equal conditions into one WHERE clause - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing the SQL exercise and got a question about `WHERE` clause.

```
 - Write an SQL query to find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively. 

*Logs table:*

id   Num
 1    1
 2    1
 3    1
 4    2
 5    1
 6    2
 7    2
```

My sql query code is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Num AS ConsecutiveNums FROM Logs AS a
INNER JOIN Logs AS b ON  a.Id + 1 = b.Id
INNER JOIN Logs AS c ON a.Id + 2 = c.Id
WHERE a.Num = b.Num = c.Num;
```

When I write condition as `WHERE a.Num = b.Num = c.Num`, the result shows  `{"headers": ["ConsecutiveNums"], "values": [[1], [2]]}`, which is not correct. But when I separate the condition to `WHERE a.Num = b.Num AND b.Num = c.Num`, the result is `{"headers": ["ConsecutiveNums"], "values": [[1]]}`, which is correct.

Could anyone please tell the principle of the WHERE clause regarding this situation?

Comment: Hint:  Think. `GROUP BY`.

Comment: `WHERE a.Num = b.Num = c.Num` returns only `1` just like `WHERE a.Num = b.Num AND b.Num = c.Num`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=26954680b318110e616cd7fffe785f06

Comment: Hi Gordon, sorry I still don't get it, after the table has been self joined three times, Num's three columns can be imagined as sharing each row, so if there is a `GROUP BY`, it will be applied to each row for three columns as well? But why I cannot combine these three columns together in the clause?

Comment: Your query is correct, but you cannot write WHERE a.Num = b.Num = c.Num, write instead WHERE a.Num = b.Num AND b.Num = c.Num

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do it is with:

```
WHERE a.Num = b.Num AND b.Num = c.Num
```

When you use:

```
WHERE a.Num = b.Num = c.Num
```

the result you get is coincidental.

It has to do with the operator `=` and MySql's feature to evaluate boolean expressions like `x = y` as `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`.

So, this boolean expression:

```
a.Num = b.Num = c.Num
```

is evaluated as:

```
(a.Num = b.Num) = c.Num
```

and since the result of `(a.Num = b.Num)` can be either `0` or `1`, the whole expression is equivalent to:

```
0 = c.Num
```

or:

```
1 = c.Num
```

But there is no row with `Num = 0` in the table, so the only case that the boolean expression will evaluate to `1` (`true`) is if `Num = 1` and this is the result you get (coincidentally).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT NUM
FROM Logs as main
WHERE
NUM = (SELECT NUM FROM Logs WHERE ID = main.ID +1)
AND NUM = (SELECT NUM FROM Logs WHERE ID = main.ID +2)
```

Since this looks like a piece of homework, I hope you understand how each part of the query work, and why it works.

Comment: Hi Rui, thank you for your reply, but the answer you just shared might not work for this question, that needs to select the Num which appeared 3 times *consecutively*.  The query code I posted above actually works if I put WHERE a.Num = b.Num AND b.Num = c.Num. But I am confused about why I cannot use WHERE a.Num = b.Num = c.Num.

Comment: You are correct, please check the edit. When you want more than 1 comparison, you need to use an `AND`

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct l1.Num as ConsecutiveNums
from 
Logs l1, 
Logs l2, 
Logs l3
where l1.Id = l2.Id-1
and l2.Id = l3.Id-1
and l1.Num=l2.Num
and l2.Num=l3.Num
```

**Hope this helps you**